# Can't access mail item in ATL/COM C++ Outlook Addin

Tags: c++, outlook, com, outlook-addin, atl

I am trying to get the mail information and do some actions based on the values when the user hits the send button in Outlook. Therefore I use this function:

`VOID WINAPI CConnect::ItemSend(IDispatch * Item, bool Cancel)`

In the OnConnection event handler I call

```
DispEventAdvise((IDispatch*)m_Application, &__uuidof(Outlook::ApplicationEvents));
```

It is implemented in the Header-File like this:

```
public IDispEventSimpleImpl<1, CConnect, &__uuidof(Outlook::ItemEvents)>

public:

VOID WINAPI ItemSend(IDispatch * Item, bool Cancel);

BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CConnect)
SINK_ENTRY_INFO(1, __uuidof(Outlook::ItemEvents), 0x0000F002, ItemSend, &fiMailItemEvents)
END_SINK_MAP()
```

This is working just like it should, but inside the function I try to get the mail item I always get an exception. This is my code for accessing the item:

```
CComPtr<Outlook::_MailItem> mail;
Item->QueryInterface(IID__MailItem, (void**)&mail);
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the `HRESULT` return value of `QueryInterface()`?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't return anything because the Application always crashes with  error '0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback'

Comment: [`QueryInterface()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521(v=vs.85).aspx) returns a HRESULT, however you are not checking its value. Simply edit your code like this: `HRESULT hr = Item->QueryInterface(IID__MailItem, (void**)&mail);`. Then place a breakpoint on the next line to see the value of `hr`.

Comment: It should return a result, but at this exact point Outlook crashes so the HRESULT value will not be set and there is no way to retrieve it. Maybe there is a problem with the Item, but I don't know what could be causing it...

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with your event handler. Are you implementing `IDispEventImpl` or `IDispEventSimpleImpl` in your class?

Comment: I have updated my question. Do you see anything wrong with this?

Comment: Could you post your `fiMailItemEvents` structure as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of caveats in your code, which could lead to problems:

- Your `ItemSend()` method differs from the one in Outlook's type library. It should be declared as `ItemSend(IDispatch* Item, VARIANT_BOOL* Cancel)`.
- The pointer to the event dispinterface's IID in your `IDispEventSimpleImpl` template declaration points to `Outlook::ItemEvents`. However, you are interested in handling events from `Outlook::ApplicationEvents`.
- Although not crucial, your call to `DispEventAdvise()` casts the application interface pointer to `IDispatch*`, whereas the function expects an `IUnknown*` parameter. You may also omit the second parameter.

The following class demonstrates how to handle the `ItemSend` event accordingly. Since you are implementing the `IDTExtensibility2` interface, you'll need to move the initialization and cleanup routines to its `OnConnection` and `OnDisconnection` methods respectively.

```
_ATL_FUNC_INFO fiMailItemEvents = { CC_STDCALL, VT_EMPTY, 2, { VT_DISPATCH, VT_BOOL | VT_BYREF } };

class CConect : 
    public ATL::IDispEventSimpleImpl<1, CConect, &(__uuidof(Outlook::ApplicationEvents))>
    {
public:
    CConect(Outlook::_ApplicationPtr piApp)
    {
        m_piApp = piApp;
        DispEventAdvise((IUnknown*)m_piApp);        
    }

    virtual ~CConect()
    {
        DispEventUnadvise((IUnknown*)m_piApp);
    }

    void __stdcall OnItemSend(IDispatch* Item, VARIANT_BOOL* Cancel)
    {
        CComPtr<Outlook::_MailItem> mail;
        HRESULT hr = Item->QueryInterface(__uuidof(Outlook::_MailItem), (void**)&mail);
    }

    BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CConect)
        SINK_ENTRY_INFO(1, __uuidof(Outlook::ApplicationEvents), 0x0000F002, OnItemSend, &fiMailItemEvents)     
    END_SINK_MAP()

private:

    Outlook::_ApplicationPtr m_piApp;
};
```

Comment: You are absolutely right with your points. I tried to use Outlook::ApplicationEvents earlier, but couldn't figure it out correctly, but thanks to your code it is working now. I really appreciate your effort!

Comment: Great to hear. Thanks for your feedback.